# Can I get setTimeOut() executed after page redirection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, settimeout

Why not Duplicate: Question wasn't answered in previous post.

I have a delete link, which when get clicked triggers a popup which contains a button. When I click that button, then the page (inside the popup) gets redirected to a new internal page. What I want to achieve is that the pop-up should close after 1 second after the redirection has happened. I applied the function when the button is clicked which is only available before the "Popup Redirection".

```
    $('.page-user-cancel .btn').click(function(e) {
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    setTimeout( function(){
        function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
        }
    }  , 1000 );
});
```

If I am not clear, please comment. English is not my native language.

**EDIT**

If that is not feasible, is it possible to trigger the function when the div on the new page (after redirection) gets loaded?

**UPDATE**

This isn't working:

```
var dival = $('.inside .alert').length;
if (dival > 0){
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
        }
}
else{}
```

It works, only after refreshing.

Got it Worked: Had to remove the function call of refreshParent. might not be the best practice, but it is working that way.

Comment: Better would be to have the redirected page inside the pop-up close itself, rather than trying to close via the parent. You can do this via `window.close()`

Comment: Somehow I don't have access to the new page, url changes dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is not possible since, reloading the page doesn't keep `JavaScript` of the previous page running.

Second part is better. Yes, you can handle page load:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Check your div here
});
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but it gets executed without respecting timeout function.

Comment: how do I check my div? I've read that we cannot use load() on div elements.

Comment: `$('div#id-of-div').length > 0` if `div` exists

Comment: thank you, my first user test is passed, moving to next. :)